# Command for adding API KEY to ngrok.yml file doesn't work

Tags: java, ngrok, pyngrok

This command `ngrok config add-authtoken <API KEY>` on the [documentation](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup) doesn't work for me.
If you are having a hard time looking for a solution try this code **`ngrok authtoken <YOUR API KEY>`** and it will add your **ngrok API KEY** to the config file which is
***ngrok.yml*** in ***`~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`***

**Note: This helped on a windows machine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that, unfortunately, `ngrok` doesn't version its docs. If you installed `ngrok` through `pyngrok`, [you installed v2](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok#ngrok-version-compatibility), but `ngrok`'s site now hosts v3 docs, as it came out recently. The v2 command to install your auth token is:

```
ngrok authtoken <YOUR API KEY>
```

You can peruse the v2 docs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220327044111/https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-authtoken).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot I now understand. But does it have to be the version 2 you always get when you install `ngrok` through `pyngrok` ?

Comment: Until it’s updated to support v3, yes. There are breaking changes between the two versions.